# How can I query CSV values and output them as a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

We deal with a lot of different kinds of CSV files. All the CSV files are slightly different, but they all have a sort of primary key that is constant across all of them .I have a database that stores the data from these CSVs in Postgresql (11.10) that looks roughly like this:

```
Files
+--+----+--------+
|id|name|headers | 
+--+----+--------+
|1 |file|pk,b,c  |
+--+----+--------+
|2 |ifle|pk,b,d,e|
+--+----+--------+
|3 |life|pk,e,f,g|
+--+----+--------+
|................|


Records
+--+------+---------+--------+
|id|fileID|record_pk|record  |
+--+------+---------+--------+
|1 |1     |1        |1,2,3   |
+--+------+---------+--------+
|2 |1     |1        |1,5,6   |
+--+------+---------+--------+
|3 |1     |7        |7,8,9   |
+--+------+---------+--------+
|4 |2     |1        |1,f,o,o |
+--+------+---------+--------+
|5 |2     |2        |2,b,a,r |
+--+------+---------+--------+
|6 |3     |1        |1,b,a,z |
+--+------+---------+--------+
|............................|
```

What I'd like to do is query for a single PK within a single file, and get a queryable table of the results.  For example, I may want to get data from file 1 for PK 1 from the above. I want the output to be:

```
+--+-+-+
|pk|b|c|
+--+-+-+
|1 |2|3|
+--+-+-+
|1 |5|6|
+--+-+-+
```

For another example, I may want to get data from file 2 for PK 2, and the output would be:

```
+--+-+-+-+
|pk|b|d|e|
+--+-+-+-+
|2 |b|a|r|
+--+-+-+-+
```

Is such a query actually possible?

Comment: what column type is RECORDS.RECORD?

Comment: Both FILE.HEADER and RECORDS.RECORD is TEXT

Comment: I'm not convinced it's impossible, but it's definitely a tricky problem. I would use regexp_split_to_array() to parse the data in RECORD, and i might try the same on headers and just doing a UNION ALL so that the first row is the header name. FWIW hdfs platform like hadoop might be perfectly designed for this.